# set custom height and width to sweat-alert

Tags: flutter, dart

I have applied `sweetalert` in my project my application is in landscape direction and `sweetalert` take the full screen I want to set custom width and height to `sweetalert`.

```
SweetAlert.show(context,
                      title: "Just show a message",
                      subtitle: "Sweet alert is pretty",
                      style: SweetAlertStyle.confirm,
                      showCancelButton: true, onPress: (bool isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
          SweetAlert.show(context,style: SweetAlertStyle.success,title: "Success");
          // return false to keep dialog
          return false;
        }
      });
```

Comment: There is no specific properties like height and weight in SweetAlert, But i have one hack if you fine

Comment: yeah I do search but I could not fine specific properties like this. sure share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any option according to my assessment for your question. but I think `rflutter_alert` is the best option to use instead of `sweetalert` here you can use the width and height to customize it. Hope that will help you. you can add multiple buttons in buttons: [],

```
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
    Alert(
          context: context,
          type: AlertType.error,
          title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
          desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
          buttons: [
            DialogButton(
              child: Text(
                "COOL",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              width: 120,
            )
          ],
        ).show();
```

Comment: look,  you are more than awesome. It is pretty cool that is what I want sir.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, wrap your string with three quote (''' String '''), Add space or new lines what you want base on your expected height.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/String-class.html

```
                        SweetAlert.show(
                            context,
                            title: '''

            Just show a message

                            ''',
                            subtitle: '''


            Sweet alert is pretty


                                ''',
                            style: SweetAlertStyle.confirm,
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            onPress: (bool isConfirm) {
                            if (isConfirm) {
                                SweetAlert.show(context,
                                    style: SweetAlertStyle.success, title: "Success");
                                // return false to keep dialog
                                return false;
                            }
                            },
                        );
```

[image]

Comment: I want to reduce the width actually :(

Comment: @Developer I think for that you have to do custom development for dialog, if I found better solution will share it.

Comment: ok thanks Amit. can you share beautiful dialog like this? I search but I could not find